# print() outputs to console with delay after exception, breaking logging order

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following validation routine:

```
def validate_schema(self, name, data, schema_filename):
    Logging.message("validating {0} against schema".format(name))
    with open(schema_filename) as f:
        schema = json.load(f)
        resolver = jsonschema.RefResolver(
            "file:///{0}/".format(os.path.abspath(schema_filename.rsplit('/', 1)[0])), schema
        )
        jsonschema.validate(data, schema, resolver=resolver)
        Logging.ok()
```

class Logging contains:

```
@staticmethod
def ok():
    print("OK")

@staticmethod
def message(msg):
    print("> " + msg, end='... ')
```

When schema validation fails, I get exception text first, and "validating..." message following it.

Why is this happening and how to keep output order?

Answer (score 1):

Flushing `stdout` does the trick

```
@staticmethod
def message(text):
    print("> " + text, end='... ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```